# Render partial located in child directory in Phoenix

Tags: templates, elixir, phoenix-framework, partials

If a partial is in the same folder as another `.eex` file, you can just run `render "filename.html"`, but what if it's in a subfolder? In my case, I have a bunch of partials containing the HTML for some SVG icons. I don't want those files cluttering up the main template directory for my controller (I'd rather have them in `templates/pages/icons` than `templates/pages`). If they're not in the same directory as the `.eex` file that's rendering them, though, referring to them by name doesn't work, nor do things like `render "icons/filename.html"`. What's the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to first modify your *web/web.ex* file to let it know to include subdirectories:

`use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates", pattern: "**/*"`

After making this change you can just use relative paths like so: `"icons/filename.html"`

Hope that helps!

Comment: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-render-a-template-inside-a-web-templates-folder-subfolder/1404/6